# What is the Right Context of a Word in Formal Langauge Theory?

Tags: inverse, automata, formal-languages, pattern-matching

I am reading this [paper](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Emac/REC/DOC/B4.ps) and am unable to understand this notation in section 2.2 -

> The *right context* of a word $u$  according to a language $W$ is the language {$u^{-1}w$ | $w \in W$}. The equivalence generated over $A^{*}$ by the relations $$u^{-1}W  = v^{-1}W, \space \space u,v \in A^{*}$$
>
> is denoted by $\equiv_W$; it is the right syntactic congruence associated with the language $W$

What is the physical interpretation of $u^{-1}$ for some word $u$? If $u^{-1}$ is defined such that $uu^{-1} = \epsilon$ i.e. the word that cancels out a prefix which it is the inverse of, then what happens in $u^{-1}w$, if $w$ does not contain $u$ as a prefix?

If $u$ = "apple" and $v$ = "orange", then what is the string $u^{-1}v$?

Comment: In another words, $u^{-1}W$ are right parts of strings from $W$, which begins with $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would understand it as a (confusing/sloppy) way to define the "right context" of $u$ to mean the set
$$ \{v\in A^*\mid uv\in W\} $$

There is no inverse operation in formal language theory in general. Formal languages are generally supposed to be subsets of *free monoids*, which do not have inverses. Assuming that inverses exist would amount to speaking about *free groups* instead, which is a rather different theory.

Comment: So then how would we interpret $u^{-1}W = v^{-1}W$?

Comment: @BanachTarski: I would take that to mean $\{x\in A^*\mid ux\in W\}=\{x\in A^* \mid vx\in W\}$.

Comment: Oh I see! So if we have an automaton which accepts the language $W$ then all words belonging to the same right syntactic congruence might reach the same state after begin passed into the automaton. Thanks! that clarified a lot!